# Redirect after AJAX form submission

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Using MVC 4, I have a partial view form which contains an `@Ajax.BeginForm`.

The form submits as expected, and the result is displayed asynchronously in my main view.

I want a condition on my controller that if a certain parameter is true on my form, then it redirects to a whole new page (instead of displaying the result in my main view).

When I tried `return RedirectToAction`, the whole view displays in the div that the form normally displays in, as opposed to ignoring the AJAX and redirecting to a completely new page.

Does anyone know how I can acheive this?

Comment: @loveforfire..if you can show some code..it would be easy to understand

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667447/return-partial-view-and-json-from-asp-net-mvc-action  the redirect has to happen on the view side.  pass the variable through with the ajax call and if its true do a window.location

Comment: If the decision parameter is available to the client, then I would control the partial vs reload behaviour from the client, i.e. redirect instead of ajax if `parameter == true`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `return JavaScript` to achieve it.

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    if (parameter)
    {
        return JavaScript("window.location = '" + Url.Action("Action", "Controller") + "'");
    }
    //Do something here
    return PartialView("ParitalView", Model);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could not perform `RedirectToAction` in a ajax call.

Just return a `HttpStatusCodeResult` and based on it perform redirect in Javascript

```
public ActionResult Save()
{

   return new HttpStatusCodeResult(302,
            "/Users/Details");
}
```

In Ajax Error function, set in `AjaxOptions { OnFailure = "Error" }`

```
function Error(response, status, error) {
    window.location.href= response.statusText;
}
```