# Kendo UI submit button click and transition to view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, onclick

I have a login form on a view and if the login is successful (when the user clicks on the login button) I would like to transition the user to another view. How can I change the click event of the login button to support the successful login and transition to the new view?

```
<a class="button button-block button-submit" data-role="button" href="#welcome/view.html" data-bind="events: { click: form.submit }">Login</a>
```

Comment: if your form is ajaxified you should redirect on ajax complete, if not you should redirect server side.

Comment: I have used ajax call to confirm the login and would like to redirect the user to a different view on login. Any suggestions how?

Comment: you should use ajax success callback event to redirect with location.href

Comment: Can you possibly show it with an example in the answer? I have been trying but no luck so far.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20974447/mvc-redirect-ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here:
http://www.telerik.com/forums/button-press-event---transition-to-a-view

I just used AJAX call to allow the user to login and use the success event of that to allow the user to navigate to a different view using the function given below:

```
app.mobileApp.navigate('home/view.html');
```