# Is there any way to provide the contents of a Razor view from a string variable rather than from a file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, view

Example --

```
var myView = "<p>The date is @DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()</p>";
return View(myView);
```

Essentially, I want to override the MVC view resolution functionality which looks for the view on the file system.  Instead of reading the Razor codein from a file, I want to provide it as a string.

(Why? So I can compile Views in a separate DLL and drop them into projects.  Let me know if I'm going about this the completely wrong way.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730777/mvc-return-partial-view-as-json

Comment: That's the exact opposite of what I want.  I don't want to RENDER a view as a string, I want to PROVIDE a view as a string.

Comment: so the answer to your question is yes.  the link I gave turns a view into a string.  Look at the format and you can create your string views as the same format and render them on the view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667447/return-partial-view-and-json-from-asp-net-mvc-action

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) to parse Razor from a string:

```
    string result = RazorEngine.Razor.Parse("<p>The date is @DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()</p>");
    return Content(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller class has one method named content which returns ContentResult

in your action you can use it like `Content("your string content");`

to your content you can configure this things

```
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the content.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The content.
        public string Content { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the content encoding.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The content encoding.
        public Encoding ContentEncoding { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the type of the content.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The type of the content.
        public string ContentType { get; set; }
```