# Returning Partialview & JSON from MVC 5 Controller

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

In an MVC5 project, I open a modal dialog and in case there is an exception, I want to open this dialog and display a message on a div in this dialog. As far as I see, I should follow the approach as rendering partialview into a string, but most of the examples does not work in MVC5 as on [Return Partial View and JSON from ASP.NET MVC Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667447/return-partial-view-and-json-from-asp-net-mvc-action). Is there any similar or better approach working for MVC5?

Comment: you want to show the errors on the modal and not the partial view it self with errors right?

Comment: Actually I render the partial view for create, update, etc. and if there is an error in the Create action method in the controller, I want to render _Error partialview instead of _Create and display some messages (returned from the action method as json) in the _Error partialview.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can  do the following

**Solution 1 ( using partial views)**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourAction(YourModel model)
{
    if(model!=null && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
          // do your staff here
          Response.StatusCode = 200; // OK
          return PartialView("ActionCompleted");
    }
    else
    {
          Response.StatusCode = 400; // bad request
          // ModelState.ToErrors() : is an extension method that convert 
          // the model state errors  to dictionary
          return PartialView("_Error",ModelState.ToErrors());
    }
}
```

Your partial view should look like:

```
<div id="detailId">
     <!-- Your partial details goes here -->
     ....
         <button type="submit" form="" value="Submit">Submit</button>

</div>
```

your script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#formId').off('submit').on('submit', function(e){
               e.preventDefault();
               e.stopPropagation();

               var form = $('#formId');
               $.ajax({
                   url: form.attr('action'),
                   data: form.serialize(),
                   method: 'post',
                   success : function(result){
                        $('#detailId').replaceWith(result);
                        // another option you can close the modal and refresh your data.
                   },
                   error: function(data, status, err){
                       if(data.status == 400){
                           $('#detailId').replaceWith(data.responseText);
                       }
                   }
               });

         });
    });
</script>
```

**Solution 2 ( using Json)**

in your action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourAction(YourModel model)
{
    if(model!=null && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
          // do your staff here              
          return Json(new {status = 200, 
                           //...any data goes here... for example url to redirect
                        url=Url.Content("YourRedirectAction","Controller")},
    }
    else
    {              
          return Json( new {status= 400,errors = ModelState.ToErrors()});
    }
}
```

and your script should look like

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#formId').off('submit').on('submit', function(e){
               e.preventDefault();
               e.stopPropagation();

               var form = $('#formId');
               $.ajax({
                   url: form.attr('action'),
                   data: form.serialize(),
                   method: 'post',
                   success : function(result){
                        if(result.status==200) { // OK
                            // you might load another action or to redirect
                            // this conditions can be passed by the Json object
                        }
                        else{ // 400 bad request
                            // you can use the following toastr based on your comment
                            // http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html
                             var ul = $('<ul>')
                             for(var error in result.errors)
                             {
                                 ul.append('<li><b>' + error.Key + '</b>:' + error.Value + '</li>;
                             }
                             toastr["warning"](ul[0].outerHTML);
                        }
                   }
               });

         });
    });
</script>
```

Finally, if you want the extension `ModelState.ToErrors()`

```
public static IEnumerable ToErrors(this ModelStateDictionary modelState)
{
     if (!modelState.IsValid)
     {
         return modelState.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key,
                 kvp => kvp.Value.Errors
                           .Select(e => e.ErrorMessage).First())
                           .Where(m => m.Value.Count() > 0);
     }
     return null;
}
```

hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will give a try. Voted+

Comment: Not actually, but I preferred to use another approach and display toast message without opening modal dialog. Thanks...

Comment: toast message will contains the errors only, I asked you on your question comments how you want it, i will update the answer

Comment: @binary I updated the answer to include anotther approash

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid example, i have used this technique many times.
If it is a simple get call than i would suggest make a partial view of data you want to show and call it via jquery with code below.

```
$( "#result" ).load("@Url.Action("Account","HelloPartial")");
```

this will load the partial view its self in the popup. you won't have to convert it to strings.